# Why is bold vectorization of "v"not working?

Tags: symbols, bold, boldmath

So I have the following setup in my preamble,

```
\def\ve#1{\mathchoice{\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle\bf#1$}}
    {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle\bf#1$}}
    {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle\bf#1$}}
    {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle\bf#1$}}}  

\newcommand{\y}{{\ve y}} 

\renewcommand{\v}{{\ve v}}
```

But now in the text when I am calling $\y$ it does get the bold faced $y$ by on calling $\v$ the same does not happen for v? For v I am getting an error,

```
Improper \spacefactor. <recently read> \spacefactor
```

Can someone help fix this?

Comment: Don't show code snippets, always make a (small but) complete example starting with \documentclass. And better don't redefine accent commands like \v.

Comment: What is an accent command? What is special about "v"? This code as I pasted above works for everything except "v"!

Comment: Plus why are you using `\bf` it has been depreciated since 1993!!! A simple `\mathbf{#1}` is enough, or even better use `\bm{#1}` from the `bm` package to get a bold italic char.

Comment: you should never use `\bf` in latex, but why is the definition so complicated rather than just `\bm{y}` ? Are you sure the `\spacefactor` error comes from the code you have shown?

Comment: If you do not know exactly what a macro does then NEVER redefine it!!!!

Comment: With *re*newcommand you are *re*defining an existing command. That is not a good idea if you don't know what the original command is doing.

Comment: An accent command is a command that puts an accent. `\v` will put an inverted hat on a symbol. And, in addition to what @daleif is saying, you could use `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: So are you saying that there is no analogous way to define \v as we can do with any other alphabet? We want a short-cut for bold vector $v$!

Comment: `\v` is a core command in latex, if you redefine it you will break any text using that accent, which is quite possible in bibliographies etc, even if your document is in English.

Comment: But this \renewcommand on \v does work in many of my files. Its this one particular file where I am seeing this problem!

Comment: Presumably a document that has an accented letter in, however the definition is wrong always, even if by chance you get away with it in some cases., It is wrong to redefine `\v` and your definition with `\mathchoice` is wrong and the use as `{{\ve y{}}` is wrong (it should be `\ve{y}`)

Comment: @gradstudent I'm sorry that you've got a lot of people chiming in to tell you you're doing things wrong, they're genuinely trying to save you pain in the long run :) So I'm afraid I have to join them and take issue with what you said "So are you saying that there is no analogous way to define \v as we can do with any other alphabet?" There are actually many letters which are already defined and whose definitions you will need to override: (at least) `c k b d r u v t` and I think `l` and `o`. `H` also.

Comment: Even though you might not get a lot  of people using `\k{a}` in their code themselves these days, I too recommend against one-letter commands. You would like a short-cut for bold vector $v$ and there's nothing wrong with that, but there are better ways than writing over basic LaTeX commands, especially if you don't know what they do or even realise that you're writing over them